# Modeling a Brick Tower for Game Engine

Tags: modeling, unity

I have 2 ways to build a brick tower, and that is to make a cylinder and applying textures and bump maps or create the bricks separately and make it as one mesh. Which would be best for a game engine? , I think creating the bricks separately would consume a lot of memory especially if I have these towers in one area(not 100% sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. Texturing a single mesh is better.
You could also use bricks and replicate them with the Array modifier, so they are linked copies (until you apply the modifier) of the first.
But texturing remains the lightest solution, I think.

Comment: Even modelling and then baking the texture from the model  may be more memory-to-quality cost than it needs to be, in this case, because an independently created  brick  texture is likely to be tileable? But I guess  it would depend on the style @Thaana Paana is looking for..

Comment: Yeah! It would also be good!

Comment: wanted to make separate bricks at first for a more nice look. I'm working on a low poly game scene. I don't think texturing a single mesh in a low poly would be nice, but for now I'm going with the single mesh, later I will do a little experimenting on performance and update this, and thanks